# How to get current active item of carousel in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel

Currently I have a carousel with 3 item named page 1, page 2 and page 3, what I'm trying to do is to make bold text for page 2 when user switch from page 1 to page 2 by sliding animation. Can someone give me a solution how to achieve this goal. Thank you!

**App.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
'Ext': 'sdk/src'
});


Ext.application({
controllers: ["Main"],

name: 'Sencha',

views: ['Main'],

icon: {
    57: 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    72: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    114: 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    144: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

phoneStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen.jpg',
tabletStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen~ipad.jpg',

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Sencha.view.Main'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    );
}
});
```

**Main.js for view**

```
Ext.define("Sencha.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
xtype: 'mainview',

config: {
    id: 'carousel',

    fullscreen: true,

    indicator: false,

    directionLock: true,

    items: [
    {
        id: 'page1',
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: 'Page 1'
    },

    // Carousel 2
    {
            id: 'page2',
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'Page 2',
            initialize: function() {
                var carouselId = Ext.getCmp('carousel');
                var carouselIndex = carouselId.getActiveIndex();
                console.log(carouselIndex);
            }
    },


    // Carousel 3
    {
            id: 'page3',
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'Page 3'
    },
    ]

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the activate event on each carousel item. So in your controller's control config add this for your id of page two and in your corresponding function put whatever code you need to in it, it will run when the.specific carousel item is activated.

Here is an example:

```
new Ext.Carousel({
   fullscreen : true,
   defaults : {
      listeners : {
         activate : function() {
            console.log('activate');
         }
      }
   },
   items: [ 
      {
         html : 'One'
      },
      {
         html : 'Two'
      },
      {
         html : 'Three'
      }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

user `getActiveItem()` method of carousel

Comment: It give me active item but my question is current active item because this function always give me 0 for whatever I do